# Return related data from dB c#

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm, relational-database, rest-client

I have two databases which represent two objects and I am using a Rest Client to access them. One of "Object 2"'s fields is called objectOneId which is the primary key for "Object1". I have a class that is trying to query my databases in order to get the all the Objects2 that have the Object1 foreach Object1. I tried returning this in a dictionnary but IQUERYABLE does not let you do that. here some code for more explanation:

```
// GET: api/Obj1


public IQueryable<Object1> GetObject1()
    {

       Dictionary<string, List<Object2>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Object2>>();
       List<Object2> list = new List<Object2>();

       foreach(var obj1 in dB.obj1)
       {
           list.AddRange(db.obj2.Where(x => x.obj1Id == obj1.Id &&));

           dict.Add(obj1.Name, list);
       }

       return dict;
    }
```

So trying to add all the object2s that have the ID of the current obj1 being processed. I'm trying to return this by using this funtion in another class:

```
public async Task InitializeData()
        {
            //Get data from dB
            _Data = await _DataService.GetData();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var obj1 in dB.obj1) {
    var newlist = db.obj2.Where(x => x.obj1Id == obj1.Id).ToList();

    list.AddRange(newlist);

    dict.Add(obj1.Name, list);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to import the id's (primary keys) of obj1 into my code?

Comment: you may import it in to array and loop the array

Comment: var ids= dB.obj1.Select(x=>x.obj1Id );

foreach(var id in ids)
{
 var newlist = db.obj2.Where(x => x.obj1Id == id ).ToList();

}